# iPhone: Cocos2d & UIKit Code Integration

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

i am trying to record video of screen using this code: [**Link**](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673)
. I have successfully recorded screen video in UIKit. Now, I want to use the same code in Cocos2d-Box2d project. Is there any possibility that i can record screen video using UIKit's code in Cocos2d.

I am fairly new in Cocos2d (but not in programming) so i have not any idea that how to use this code in Cocos2d.

Comment: Did you give it a try?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Yeah, I have tried to add [[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] in the place of UIView which needs to be recorded. It gives me no error and no crash but produced the video file of Zero KB.

Comment: Might be because the capture method doesn't capture OpenGL framebuffers. There are GL-specific solutions to this, for example Kamcord and others. If you only need to record footage for your own use (trailer etc.) playback & record via Airplay works perfectly. There's Airserver and my personal favorite Reflector.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I think Kamcord might help me. I'll try it.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D yeah man Kamcord is giving me the exact same effect with smooth video. but the problem is that it overrides the previous video when we record another video (WHICH I DO NOT WANTED TO DO) and another problem is that i cannot change the path of video which is necessary for me. Do you know any way to do these two things?